# Mat-Datepicker: how to use ja-JP Dateformat but keep english datepicker language

Tags: date, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I want the date-format "YYYY/MM/DD" and therefore I use 'ja-JP' in my app.module

```
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'ja-JP'},
]
```

I get the right date-format "YYYY/MM/DD" but the datepicker is displayed in japanese.

[image]

I would like to keep the default layout

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use following way to convert date as yyyy-mm-dd . this will work .

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, } from '@angular/material/core';

import { MomentDateAdapter, } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@NgModule( {

providers: [
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },

{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_FORMATS },
]

})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Install @angular/material-moment-adapter using npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter